# How do I update a join query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that can be joined on a key. All I want to do is to update one of the attributes of table1 using a condition on table 2

```
UPDATE t1 
 INNER JOIN t2
    ON t1.id= t2.id
   SET t2.column3 = 'dte'  
 WHERE t1.column = 456
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Comment: You should provide details of what you tried, what worked and what didn't.. And question has to be very specific

Comment: The rdbms is sql.

Comment: SQL is query language not RDBMS

Comment: SQL is the language, RDBMS would be Oracle, MySQL etc...

Comment: Microsoft sql server

Comment: @juergend my question is how do I go about it

Comment: @boredcoder thanks. I've make an edit to my post

Comment: @user2023608 Microsoft sql server. I'm a rookie. It's written all over me

Answer (score 0):

i think SET clause should be after UPDATE clause then your JOIN. also you are trying to update column3 from table t2, the table t2 should be in the UPDATE clause since that is the one you will updating

```
UPDATE t2
   SET column3 = 'dte' 
 INNER JOIN t1
    ON t2.id = t1.id    
 WHERE t1.column = 456
```